# Xcode ui tests do nothing

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa

I wrote simple test, add accessibility feature for Xcode, run it:

```
import XCTest

class MyUITests: XCTestCase {
    var app: XCUIApplication!

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        continueAfterFailure = false

        app = XCUIApplication()
        app.launch()
    }

    func testWrongUsernameOrPassword() {
        print("Debug something")
        let signInWindow = app.windows["Sign In"]

        signInWindow.textFields["Your email address"].typeText("Incorrect username")

        let passwordTextField = signInWindow.textFields["Password"]
        passwordTextField.click()
        passwordTextField.typeText("Incorrect password")
        signInWindow.buttons["Login"].click()

    }

}
```

App launched, and then nothing happens. No crashes, no debug string. Nothing.

In debug output only:

```
Test Case '-[MyUITests.MyUITests testWrongUsernameOrPassword]' started.
    t =     0.00s     Start Test at 2017-07-31 22:28:01.794
    t =     0.00s     Set Up
    t =     0.01s         Launch test.com.MyApp
```

Comment: Is your test class part of your testing or UI testing target? And do your testing targets specify the module that they're testing?

Comment: @NRitH For first question - yes. > And do your testing targets specify the module that they're testing?   I don't know what is this

Comment: i created test in file that generated when i added UI tests target to my project

Comment: I followed this tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/150073/ios-unit-testing-and-ui-testing-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're not seeing your not seeing your "Debug something" output is because you're looking at the UITest stack frame, switch to your app's stack frame to see your print output. Use Xcode's **Choose stack frame** popup, example shown below:

[image]

Comment: I just created a MyUITests class in my project and copied your code into it. The tests made it to testWrongUsernameOrPassword() and hit print("Debug something") but as expected failed on the next line because my project doesn't have a "Sign In" window. Doesn't fix your problem but at least you know your code is not the problem.

Comment: One thing to look at: The output shows "MyUITests.MyUITests testWrongUsernameOrPassword" and I'd expect it to look more like "YourAppNameUITests.MyUITests.testWrongUsernameOrPassword". You might want to check your UITest targets PRODUCT MODULE NAME. Good luck!